# Is there any way to remove backround on OxyPlot HeatMapSeries?

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

HeatMapSeries renders all area from `X0,Y0` to `X1,Y1` by default. Is there any way to avoid rendering points with value `double.NaN`?

[image: How I want it to be]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this by setting the `ColorAxis.InvalidNumberColor` property to `OxyColors.Transparent` (or another color of your choice), for example when you create the axis:

```
PlotModel model = ...;
model.Axes.Add(new LinearColorAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Right, Palette = OxyPalettes.Jet(500), `InvalidNumberColor = OxyColors.Transparent` });
```

This property defaults to `OxyColors.Gray`, hence the solid color you are seeing.

Additional examples in the example library: https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/blob/develop/Source/Examples/ExampleLibrary/Series/HeatMapSeriesExamples.cs#L116